# GemBox.Spreadsheet last used row

Tags: c#, excel, gembox-spreadsheet

I am trying to get the index of the last used row in a spreadsheet. I've found that in excel it could be done like that:

```
int lastUsedRow = worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell,

Type.Missing).Row;
```

But this doesn't seem to work with GemBox. The idea is that I have a template excel file that I want to fill with more information and therefore need the last row, so that I can continue on the next one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you can just use [ExcelFile.Rows.Count](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/P_GemBox_Spreadsheet_ExcelRowColumnCellCollectionBase_Count.htm) property.

> Gets the number of currently allocated elements (dynamically changes when worksheet is modified)

Try the following:

```
int lastUsedRow = worksheet.Rows.Count - 1;
```

Also regarding the shahkalpesh suggestion, yes you can also achieve your task with that approach as well, here is how:

```
var usedRange = worksheet.GetUsedCellRange(true);
int lastUsedRow = usedRange.LastRowIndex;
```

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for the delayed answer. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Note: I haven't used Gembox. My answer is based on searching in the documentation.

[`GetUsedCellRange`](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/M_GemBox_Spreadsheet_ExcelWorksheet_GetUsedCellRange_1.htm) returns a `CellRange`, which has a property named [`LastRowIndex`](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/P_GemBox_Spreadsheet_CellRange_LastRowIndex.htm).

Does this work the same way as Excel?

Comment: Thanks! I actually got here while searching for the last used column, not row. your answer is great